# Does overriding Service.OnStartCommand put the service into the started state?

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle, android-service-binding

In the [bound services documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Lifecycle), it says

> When a service is unbound from all clients, the Android system destroys it (unless it was also started with a `startService()` call). As such, you don't have to manage the lifecycle of your service if it's purely a bound service—the Android system manages it for you based on whether it is bound to any clients.
> However, if you choose to implement the `onStartCommand()` callback method, then you must explicitly stop the service, because the service is now considered to be started. In this case, the service runs until the service stops itself with `stopSelf()` or another component calls `stopService()`, regardless of whether it is bound to any clients.

Does this mean that simply implementing `onStartCommand` automagically puts the service into a started state when a client binds to it?

I've been looking for a way to guarentee that when a client binds to the service, the service is in the started state. So far, the only way I've been able to do it is by having the client call `startService` followed by `bindService`. But if the above is correct, then all I have to do is implement `onStartCommand` and the client is free to just call `bindService`.

Comment: `onStartCommand` is callback method to consume `startService` requests, act of overriding it doesn't change the fact the latter still has to be called to enter started state.

Comment: @Pawel That is what I thought. So, just to confirm, the quote "if you choose to implement the onStartCommand() callback method, then you must explicitly stop the service" is wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong just assumes you understand the implication that by implementing the `onStartCommand()` callback your service is capable of being started and as such it should also be properly stopped.

Comment: @Pawel your `Service` is capable of being started even if you don't implement `onStartCommand()`. There is already a default implementation of `onStartCommand()` that will be called when you call `startService()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that the documentation is wrong. Simply implementing `onStartCommand()` changes nothing. Especially because you don't implement it, you **override the method**, because there is already an existing default implementation of `onStartCommand()`

When you bind to a `Service`, the `Service` isn't technically "started", it is just bound. `onStartCommand()` will not be called unless something calls `startService()`.